# How to manage Lambda Layers in Terraform?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I keep my Terraform code in Git, and my Terraform contains a `aws_lambda_layer_version` resource. Now, I don't want to keep it as a `.zip`file. Rather, I'm trying the following approach: Keep a `requirements.txt` file with the Python dependencies that I want to include in the layer, and whenever this file changes, create a new version of the layer:

```
resource "null_resource" "layer_file" {
 
  triggers = {
    value = filebase64sha256("${path.root}/layer/requirements.txt")
  }
 
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
        mkdir python
        pip install -r layer/requirements.txt --target ./python
        zip -r layer/layer.zip python/
    EOT
  }
}
 
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "python_requests" {
  filename   = "${path.root}/layer/layer.zip"
  layer_name = "BackupDeps"
 
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.10"]
 
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.root}/layer/layer.zip")
  depends_on = [null_resource.layer_file]
}
```

The problem with this is that in order for this to work, I have to run Terraform twice:

On the first run, Terraform triggers the `null_resource` since the `requirements.txt` is changed. However, the `layer.zip` is not yet updated, so the `aws_lambda_layer_version` will not be changed/updated.

On the second run, Terraform will notice that the `layer.zip` file is changed, so that it will trigger a change in the `aws_lambda_layer_version.python_requests` resource.

Is there a better way to manage this?

Comment: *I need to run Terraform twice* what do you mean by this?

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by *I have to run Terraform twice*... are you saying you have to run terraform apply twice?

Comment: @Paolo, the answer is yes.

Comment: If your version of Terraform allows converting `null_resource` to `terraform_data` then you could try that, but it would probably have the same effect due to compilation versus runtime. Otherwise that `local-exec` functionality appears to be extrinsic to infrastructure management, and could be extricated from your Terraform config to fix the issue.

Comment: How about always running the `null_resource` ? without the trigger